# Conflicts on ignored file change

Tags: git, github, netbeans

I have a ignore file looks like this:

```
# Parameters
/app/config/parameters.yml
```

Then I create this file on my GITHUB master. Only for sample file. 
I have on my local master similar file but with other parameters. 
When I try to push I have a conflict:

> Merge of HEAD with origin/master failed because of these files

Why its happening if i have .gitignore file on local and master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .gitignore file is supposed to contain files that are present in the folder but are not supposed to be part of the repo itself. Since you want parameters.yml in your repo, you shouldn't be adding it to `.gitignore` itself. Also adding it to `.gitignore` after adding a file to the repo will have no effect. What you are probably looking for is this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged /app/config/parameters.yml
```

This will will ignore any changes you have made to the parameters.yml file.

Comment: How tho undo the above mentioned in case..!

Comment: @UJIndia use the `--no-assume-unchanged` flag instead.

Answer (score 1):

A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected.

If you have committed directly on the GITHUB, then you would need to do a `git pull` on your local repo to get those changes.

If you can try to be a bit more clear on your question, we can help you better :)

For more info: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore